# Should I mark my own question as a dupe in this case?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

My question [Who stabbed Frodo?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151737/46509) is indirectly answered by a quote given in this answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21383/46509. Is this a duplicate, the questions are not really the same even though the answer does cover it.

If it's not a duplicate if someone wants to add/edit an answer with this quote in I can accept an answer.

Answer (score 5):

In this instance, my instinct is to say **no**. Although the [supposed duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21383/46509) makes reference to the incident in question (Frodo's stabbing with a "*Mordor-knife*") it certainly doesn't offer any conclusive, definitive proof regarding the ***identity*** of the person doing the stabbing, which is the whole point of the earlier question, ["Who stabbed Frodo?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151737/46509)

---

Frankly, I'm uncertain why you feel that this particular quote offers enough proof of the identity of the stabber that you'd be willing to consider an acceptance on the basis of it being added to an answer.

> "*Escaping a wound that would have been as deadly to him as the Mordor-knife to Frodo (as was proved at the end), he withdrew and hid for a while"*

Nowhere does it say who the Mordor knife *belongs to*, and hence this quote doesn't answer the question. If you could somehow show that there was only one Mordor-knife being used in the fight (or that the other Nazgul were wielding something other than Mordor-knives) then you might be able to construct a case that it's been answered *by exclusion.*

Comment: Read the quote again. It answers it perfectly. It's told from the witch kings point of view and talks of the attack. It's a perfect answer

Comment: Which part of the quote confirms that the blade is his? Can you highlight it specifically.

Comment: @po-ta-toe - If you like the quote so much, might I suggest that you use it as the basis for a self-answer.